# Google Analytics reports root as "/domain.com"

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have the following tracking code integrated on a customers page:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m) {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>`
```

When I go to [Behavior] -> [Site Content] -> [All Pages] the homepage is shown as "/domain.com"

[image]

On all my other integrations the hompage is always reported as "/" only.

What could be the cause / reason for that?

Comment: Did my answer satisfied the question? (why not?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably a hostname filter configuration within that particular report view.

Go to the admin area and check Account > Property> Select that View or just from the reporting area click admin.

1) Click in Filters
[image]

2) Look if you have any filters and check for an advanced filter with the "Hostname" parameter setup, something like this:

[image]

For example, that advanced filter configuration will produce in my reports something like

**Hostname/Request URI** ($A1$B1)

or in order words
**domainexample.com/page.html**

Comment: no, it's not the filter configuration. I have checked that already. It behaves like that even when no filters are applied.

Comment: And this is only happening with the home page?